# Flosum-Jira connector : Named Credentials errored out while accessing

Tags: namedcredentials

I am working on Flosum expert level certificate, where we integrate Jira with Flosum with Flosum Jira connector and using named credentials.

How ever its popping an error while trying to config new project with below error.

Named credentials are invalid or Service is not working now!

I am following the steps to the dot and tried couple of alternatives as well.

I am using flosum version created for certification purpose.
Jira is a trial version ( Cloud)
https://success.flosum.com/s/certifications/expert?t=lessons (lesson 29)

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take some time to read [ask] and take the [tour].  You will probably have to contact Flosum to resolve this..

Comment: Hi @DavidCheng Thank you!